# how to add google play services in export library project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I know this question has been asked here before 
[Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724808/adding-google-play-services-to-library-project)

but didn't answer yet. I export android location library using google play services when I add google play services in client project then

> Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;
>
> Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple
>   dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/R$attr;

Exceptions occur. Please suggest any solution .
Thanks for Advance

P.S : I develop on Eclipse.

Comment: # Zeeshan Shabbir I appreciate your suggestion please provide me eclipse solution if possible

Comment: you want to export the Google Play Services library? The content of your inquiry suggests you're trying to import the Google Play Services library to Eclipse. There's a lot of online resources that specifies how its done, if you check out this [hmkcode post](http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/), the project will be downloaded thru the SDK Manager and imported as a project in ADT. You'll then reference the library project in your app through its properties.